# Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ea', but it was: a custom mn object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Please help me with the solution to this errors from firebase: Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ea', but it was: a custom mn object.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { onSnapshot, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";

const ImageGrid = () => {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);
  const colRef = collection(db, 'gallery');

  const dateQuery = query(colRef, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"));

  const getData = () => {
    onSnapshot(dateQuery, (snap) => {
      let documents = [];
      snap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        documents.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      console.log(documents);
      return setDocs(documents);
    });
  };
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   getData();
  // }, []);
  return (
    <div className='img-grid'>
    <button onClick={getData}>Get Images</button>
    images
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImageGrid
```

Comment: Import `collection, orderBy` from "firebase/firestore" itself and not "firebase/firestore/lite". Also make sure you are using "firebase/firestore" in your `firebase.js` file

Comment: Thanks so much @Dharmaraj, it's solved. The main problem came from firebase.js, I imported firestore from firebase/firestore/lite. That is why I changed the importation source of collection and orderBy to firebase/firestore/lite when it was throwing errors earlier.